# Torsion-free sheaf cohomology over discrete valuation rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, deformation-theory, torsion

Let $R$ be a Henselian discrete valuation rings with algebraically closed residue field and $X$ be a regular, flat, proper $R$-scheme. Assume that the generic fiber to the natural morphism from $X$ to $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is smooth and the singular fiber is simple normal crossings divisor. Is it true that $H^i(\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a torsion-free $R$-module for $i>0$ i.e., for $K=\mathrm{Frac}(R)$, is the natural morphism from $H^i(\mathcal{O}_X)$ to $H^i(\mathcal{O}_X) \otimes_R K$ injective for all $i>0$? If not true in general, is there any known condition on $X$, under which this could hold true?

Comment: If the residue field has characteristic $0$, there are positive results (Koll'ar and Shokurov, etc.).  If the residue field has characteristic $p$, this can fail, e.g., for what are called "singular" Enriques surfaces (these are smooth, proper schemes).

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you. I am mainly interested in the case the generic fiber is rationally connected but the residue field is of positive characteristic.

Comment: I think that can happen already for the supersingular Enriques surfaces: I believe that these are dominated by rational surfaces (thus they are even unirational, not just rationally connected).

Comment: @JasonStarr Is there any known condition, we can impose on $X$ to avoid this situation?

Comment: If you assume that your scheme lifts over the Witt ring, then there are some positive results.  Please note, lifting over the Witt ring is stronger than "lifts to characteristic $0$", since you are not allowing to take roots of $p$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Could you please suggest some reference where I could read about these facts. I need this for my research and will be very helpful if you could let me know.

Comment: I do not quite know what you are asking.  I gave you some of the key names and keywords above.  If there is something specific that you need, then you can e-mail me.  However, I recommend that you just plug those key names and keywords into a search engine to get to the primary sources.

Comment: @JasonStarr I think I got it, thanks.